# 20.04 Black screen, no desktop session, org.gnome.keyring.systempropter issue

Tags: boot, gnome, keyrings, gnome-keyring

My 20.04 install is suddently not booting into gnome.  It just boots to the dreaded black screen with a blinking cursor.  I can ctrl-alt-F* my way into a virtual console, but that's it.

journalctl -xe produces the following:

```
Jan 17 15:01:32 Desktop dbus-daemon[1477]: [session uid=1000 pid=1477] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.secrets' requested by ':1.9' (uid=1000 pid=1528 comm="/usr/libexec/goa-daemon " label="unconfined")
Jan 17 15:01:32 Desktop gnome-keyring-daemon[1566]: couldn't access control socket: /run/user/1000/keyring/control: No such file or directory
Jan 17 15:01:32 Desktop gnome-keyring-d[1566]: couldn't access control socket: /run/user/1000/keyring/control: No such file or directory
Jan 17 15:01:32 Desktop dbus-daemon[1477]: [session uid=1000 pid=1477] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.secrets'
Jan 17 15:01:32 Desktop dbus-daemon[1477]: [session uid=1000 pid=1477] Activating service name='org.gnome.keyring.SystemPrompter' requested by ':1.15' (uid=1000 pid=1566 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon --start --foreground" label="unconfined")
Jan 17 15:01:32 Desktop org.gnome.keyring.SystemPrompter[1573]: Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Jan 17 15:01:32 Desktop gcr-prompter[1573]: cannot open display: 
Jan 17 15:01:32 Desktop dbus-daemon[1477]: [session uid=1000 pid=1477] Activated service 'org.gnome.keyring.SystemPrompter' failed: Process org.gnome.keyring.SystemPrompter exited with status 1
Jan 17 15:01:32 Desktop gnome-keyring-daemon[1566]: couldn't create system prompt: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process org.gnome.keyring.SystemPrompter exited with status 1
Jan 17 15:01:32 Desktop gnome-keyring-d[1566]: couldn't create system prompt: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process org.gnome.keyring.SystemPrompter exited with status 1
Jan 17 15:01:32 Desktop goa-daemon[1528]: secret_password_lookup_sync() returned NULL
Jan 17 15:01:32 Desktop goa-daemon[1528]: /org/gnome/OnlineAccounts/Accounts/account_1598527013_0: Setting AttentionNeeded to TRUE because EnsureCredentials() failed with: No credentials found in the keyring (goa-error-quark, 4)
Jan 17 15:01:42 Desktop systemd[1465]: tracker-extract.service: Succeeded.
-- Subject: Unit succeeded
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- The unit UNIT has successfully entered the 'dead' state.
Jan 17 15:01:56 Desktop pulseaudio[1471]: GetManagedObjects() failed: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.
Jan 17 15:01:56 Desktop dbus-daemon[607]: [system] Failed to activate service 'org.bluez': timed out (service_start_timeout=25000ms)
Jan 17 15:02:04 Desktop tracker-store[1554]: OK
Jan 17 15:02:04 Desktop systemd[1465]: tracker-store.service: Succeeded.
-- Subject: Unit succeeded
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- The unit UNIT has successfully entered the 'dead' state.
```

I've found some ideas for resolving this in the Arch boards, but that's it.  Any ideas are appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is also happening to me. I was trying to resolve unwanted printers constantly loading. After stopping the services related to that issue, I rebooted and got the dreaded black screen.

After 4 hours of searching and trying a lot of things, including the above boot repair, I ended up looking at my video drivers. At the command prompt, I entered

> sudo apt remove nvidia-340

I rebooted after this and it booted to my desktop environment.

Not sure if this will help you or not, but it did work for me.

Comment: Yup, that did it.  Thanks SlickTrick!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an external Ubuntu installation USB? If so, boot into the USB, and select Try Ubuntu. This will create a temporary Ubuntu session. You can now try the following:

1. Install Boot-Repair to another USB, like explained here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair and then try to run this to repair your current system.

or

2. Mount the disk where your Ubuntu is installed when running the live USB version and repair it from the command line.

It will be like running a working Ubuntu, where you can download and install all the application you need in order to have full access to repair your main installation.

I suggest you grab the files that are important to you from the main disk via the USB try version and back them up to a third USB before you attempt to repair or otherwise configure and modify the main disk.